# Публикация на стене сообщества вконтакте что не так?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

нашел решение для публикации сообщений в сообществе вконтакте с фото https://habrahabr.ru/post/226585/

```
require_once('../src/Vkontakte.php');

$accessToken = '1021c.....1cce4';
$vkAPI = new \BW\Vkontakte(['access_token' => $accessToken]);

if ($vkAPI->postToPublic(23916815, "Привет Хабр!", '../../../images/gtiradio_logo.png', ['вконтакте api', 'автопостинг', 'первые шаги'])) {

    echo "Ура! Всё работает, пост добавлен\n";

} else {

    echo "Фейл, пост не добавлен(( ищите ошибку\n";
}
```

выдает

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /home/..../public_html/php/postingvk/example/post_to_vk_group.php on line 6
```

это строка

```
 $vkAPI = new \BW\Vkontakte(['access_token' => $accessToken]);
```

Что не так?

Answer (score 1):

У Вас, скорее всего, версия php ниже версии 5.4. Начиная с неё можно использовать короткий синтаксис определения массивов `[]`, а до неё `array()`.

Comment: вот я тоже так подумал...